# Возможно ли программно заставить монитор выдавать цвет в частотах выходящих за пределы указанные в спецификациях?

Tags: экран, монитор, rgb

На днях наткнулся на несколько интересных статей говорящих о том как программно можно "разогнать" частотность матрицы монитора на частоты выходящие за пределы указанные в спецификация. Так, например, при указанных 60гц у ребят получалось на выходе 74гц.

Я начал гуглить и нашёл статью где рассказывалось как можно на аппаратном уровне увеличить яркость старого "тусклого" монитора.

И всё же мне стало интересно - можно ли на программном уровне увеличить ту же яркость выходя за пределы спецификаций устройства? Если я верно понимаю, то само ограничение на выходную картинку на экране накладывает непосредственно видео драйвер, который и является тем кто способен "позволить" получить желаемые показатели. Так ли это или же существует ещё какой-то способ манипуляции с картинкой?

Заранее огромное спасибо за помощь!